# How do I call show/hide function independently

Tags: jquery

Hi I got help and eventually I got jquery show/hide function that work well.
But I spend a whole day to do next step by make it work when there are several comment groups.

the code here

```
var toggle = false;
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.toggleComments').toggle(1000,function() {
            if(!toggle) {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br />
<div class="toggleComments" style="display:none;">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>
<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br />
<div class="toggleComments" style="display:none;">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>
<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br />
<div class="toggleComments" style="display:none;">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>
<a href="#" class="comments">Show Comments</a><br />
<div class="toggleComments" style="display:none;">This is #comment1 <br />This is #comment2 <br /></div>
```

There are 4 comment groups but because of the html DOMs are the same then they could not working independently while click each of them.

Can you please advise how to deal with this situation manage them show/hide independently without having assigned jquery script per comments group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/ZXNWF/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/X5ZUU/1/ or with text change: http://jsfiddle.net/Xam9q/

API: http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/

and then using `nextAll` always get the `:first` one to show.

rest feel free to play around with the demo, hope this help for the cause.

**code**

```
var toggle = false;
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
         $('.toggleComments').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
        $(this).nextAll('.toggleComments:first').toggle(1000,function() {
            if(!toggle) {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
​
```

**or** simple

```
var toggle = false;
$(function() {

    $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
        $('.toggleComments').hide();
        var $this = $(this);
         $('.comments').text('Show Comments');
            $this.text('Hide Comments');
        $(this).nextAll('.toggleComments:first').toggle(1000,function() {    
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
​
```

Comment: @thecodeparadox wow bruv! `:P` where were you lol Long time! thanks for +1

Comment: Hi Tats_innit Awesome, Regarding demo how to manage the others remain no change once clicking another one, please advise.

Comment: @Thanaporn you are awesome as well `:)` glad it helped you!

Comment: @Tats_innit: Check your demo, it does not always display the correct text.

Comment: @banana jsfiddle is down! I did checked and working in Alienware - chrome `:)` but anyhoo, thanks for comment

Comment: @Tats_innit: You can check it now, click once on a link, and then click on another link, the first link will remain "Hide Comments", and the second text will be "Show Comments".

Comment: @banana `:)` check this out way simpler : http://jsfiddle.net/Xam9q/ I got you what you mean now it was the text change only cheers for that - I have made it a way that there is no need of any variable `:)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want the a tags to display the correct text - use this code:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.next().next().toggle(1000,function() {
            if($this.text()=='Show Comments') {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
            }else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

(I took xdazz's answer and changed it a little, because you cannot use 1 variable (toogle) for 4 links.)
DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/jAMGE/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var toggle = false;
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.comments', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        // $this.next().next() is the div after the link.
        $this.next().next().toggle(1000,function() {
            if(!toggle) {
                $this.text('Hide Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }else {
                $this.text('Show Comments');
                toggle = !toggle;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

***[The DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9u4aA/)***.